# Changing some part of the paper after getting accepted for a conference

Tags: publications, peer-review, conference, proceedings

My paper got accepted in an A* CS conference, however, the reviewers criticized several points and suggested many others. They suggested improving the method by adopting and involving other approaches which need implementation and other further evaluations.

I agree with the reviewers on some points and I believe this would make the paper better. Consequently, the paper will be really different from the original submission. Since it is a conference and there are no further review rounds, I am wondering whether I should modify the paper (part of the method, result and maybe conclusion) based on the comments of the reviewers.

Comment: Unclear. It seems you are going to write another paper. Also in my field submitting a paper to a conference means submitting an abstract, so I don't understand if acceptance refers to you presenting your results at the conference or really a proceeding must be sent along. Normally these are separated processes.

Comment: In most (if not all) CS conferences, authors submit their entire works (similarly to journal submission).

Comment: Ok then following author recommendations is required. Likely the paper will be sent to referee again. I would personally point to the editor/conference board  that following the referees resulted in a substantially different paper too. According to the description you made, I suppose the title can be different too.

Answer (score 3):

> I am wondering whether I should modify the paper...based on the comments of the reviewers.

**Yes you should**. Acceptance was (most likely) coupled with an expectation that you'd address some or all of the comments. The reviewers (presumably) consider their comments relatively minor, since they'd have rejected otherwise, and are trusting you to make sufficient changes (that they won't check).

Comment: But these changes will change the paper completely, including its conclusion and experimental results. Your confidence increased my doubt.

Comment: Consider the reviewers' perspective: They accepted and proposed changes. Surely this suggests that the reviewers want changes implemented, otherwise,  changes wouldn't have been proposed.

Comment: I think it is unusual that reviewers want changes to _conclusions and experimental results_, since this seems like a major revision, which would merit a second round of review. But, with the information you've provided, I cannot possible know, whereas the reviewers do.

Comment: I must agree with @user2768. It is best if you honor the reviewers' comments and implement them. They have accepted and suggested you make those change. Also, bear in mind that these reviewers are senior researchers in your field with whom you will have further interaction in the future. If they find out that you ignored their comments, this will leave a negative impression on them! (and you don't want that!)